# How to stop powershell script after failed dotnet command?

Tags: powershell, .net-core

I see unreliable behaviour in the **dotnet** command when executed from a powershell script.

Executing in a powershell script:

```
dotnet build "$slnPath"
```

ignores any compilation errors and continues executing the script. I have to check **$lastexitcode** to see, if there are any errors.

On the other hand, the command:

```
dotnet test "$slnPath"
```

immediately terminates execution of the powershell script, if there are any failed unit tests.

Is that normal behavior? Do I need to write different error handling depending on the arguments of the dotnet command?

Comment: What about using `throw 1` from powershell script?

Comment: I can do that, yes. But why do I HAVE TO do that for "dotnet build" and not for "dotnet test"? What about dotnet restore, dotnet publish, etc? I find it weird that the command handles errors in different ways depending on the arguments

Answer (score -1):

The `dotnet test` command launches the test runner console application specified for a project. The test runner executes the tests defined for a unit test framework (for example, MSTest, NUnit, or xUnit) **and reports the success or failure of each test**. If all tests are successful, the test runner returns 0 as an exit code; otherwise if any test fails, it returns 1. 
But `dotnet build` building requires the project.assets.json file, which lists the dependencies of your application. The file is created when dotnet restore is executed. Without the assets file in place, the tooling can't resolve reference assemblies, which results in errors. 
You can read what each command do(and may be found some -key to control they) at this adress [tool_description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet)